# cocoa-pods failed to install pods for braintree framework in my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods, braintree

I'm working on project in which I need to install braintree, 
actually braintree was integrate and work fine but yesterday, it failed to compile with my project. 
I am integrating Braintree SDK via Cocoa-pods and always open workspace instead of opening project file.

In start, it shows me issue regarding missing of library "-lPods-myProject-braintree"

then I delete cocoa-pods (uninstall it) again install it and repeat the whole cycle of integrating braintree SDKs via Pods but now it showing me issue,
[image]

Comment: Which version of git are you using? `git --version`

Answer (score 0):

First Time I also get this type of errors but finally it solved by one line.

please run following commands in Terminal

1. go to your project folder.
2. Be sure you have installed cocoapods in your system.
3. create pod file with command - **nano podfile**
4. write **pod 'Braintree'** in your podfile.
5. save podfile and run command **pod install**
6. If you get failed to install pod.
7. then run command **pod try Braintree**
8. You will surely get your pod installed in your project with xcodeworkspace     file.